# Python, Anaconda 3 - How to Install PRAW (Windows 10)

Tags: python, installation, windows-10, spyder, praw

I am attempting to build a reddit bot using python, which I have just started learning 10 hours ago.

I am mainly a Java user, but I have also worked with C Sharp, MATLAB, SQL and the like. I would love to work on this project in Java, but as I understand it PRAW is the easiest wrapper to use for reddit.

I am using the IDE Spyder (From Anaconda 3), and am building this little bot on Windows 10. I have come across many "tutorials" that give an install command such as "pip install praw". What they don't say is WHERE to enter this command! I've tried my CMD, IPython, and Powershell.

Do I have to download pip and praw separately? Are those libraries included in Anaconda? I would greatly appreciate any clarification!

Answer (score 1):

you need to export anaconda path to environmental variables.so pip is available from command line.
then u can install from windows cmd C:>pip install praw.

> Updated
>   u need to append PATH of windows environmental variables, u can google it how to append PATH if in doubt..
>   just search environmental variables in win 10, result will pop, enter it,
>   just append user or system variable's PATH with anaconda installation directory, like in picture..
>   & u are good to go..
>   [image]
>   FYI:My anaconda is installed in %localappdata%\Continuum

Comment: Okay, that is a start. Can you clarify HOW to do this? As noted above, I am a python novice.